# Zooming effect on datagrid cell with an image in the itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am not able to figure out how to zoom the image displayed with the help of an item renderer.If i apply the Zoom effect on rollover ,the particular cell zooms the image with the scroll bars.Is their any other way of doing this without showing the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to duplicate the image and place it outside of the datagrid component. If it's inside the datagrid, it'll be forced into one of the rows. It might be helpful for you to look at the code for the DataGridDragProxy - it does does something sorta similar.